# $a \in W1\cap(W2+W3) = a \in ((W1 \cap W2) + (W1 \cap W3))$

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, vector-spaces

So  apparently I am doing something wrong because I get expression I already know is not true.

Let W1,W2,W3 vector subspaces of V

$W1\cap(W2+W3)\\
a \in (W1) \wedge a\in (W2+W3)\\$

Let b and c such that $a = b + c$

$a \in W1 \wedge b \in W2 \wedge c \in W3$

There is closure for adding in subspace therefore
$b,c \in W1$ as well

Then we get

$b \in W1 \wedge b \in W2 \wedge c \in W1 \wedge c \in W3\\
b \in (W1 \cap W2) \wedge c \in (W1 \cap W3)$

Such that $b + c = a$
And then I get

$a \in ((W1 \cap W2) + (W1 \cap W3))$

Which i know is totally wrong but i just dont get what's went wrong

Comment: The problem is in "There is closure for adding in subspace therefore $b,c∈W_1$ as well". You only know $a\in W_1$. There is no vector we know for sure is in $W_1$ that can be added to $a$ to obtain $b$ or $c$.

Comment: You my man are a life saver :)